# How can I use auth token for both organization and personnel?

Tags: github

I use "Fine-grained personal access tokens”.

However, I want to use the access token to access my personal and organization's private repositories.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [fined-grained token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token) is tied to a "Resource Owner" (Organization or user)

That means it is not meant to allow access to multiple resources.

The best practice is therefore to have separate token, one per owner.

Comment: How should I use those two tokens (organization and personnel) in one MacBook?

Comment: @hbk Are you using a different GitHub account to access the organization repositories? (different than the one used for your personal repositories?)

Comment: No. I use the same GitHub account.

Comment: @hbk Then SSH would be easier to associate two different authentications to one remote hosting service.